# Using a div for input validation with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am looking to display my input validation in a div instead of an alert. I currently have

```
//check for COGs to be a number
        if (isNaN($("#txtCOGs").val())) {
            alert("The Cost of Goods Sold must be a number");
            $("#txtCOGs").focus();
            return false;
        }
```

I am trying to place it in the div

```
<div id="divError">
```

Advice?

Comment: Not for the actual question (Bumble's answer says anything mine would!) but as a piece of advice: if your form is longer than a few fields, there's a jQuery validation plugin that might come in handy. If you're rolling your own validation, I would consider making an object containing your validation rule, relevant input element, and the error message, instead of handling it in a tonne of if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//check for COGs to be a number
        if (isNaN($("#txtCOGs").val())) {
            $("#divError").text("The Cost of Goods Sold must be a number");
            $("#txtCOGs").focus();
            return false;
 }
```

With this HTML code:

```
<div id="divError"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#divError').text("The Cost of Goods Sold must be a number");
```

or with html included:

```
$('#divError').html('<span style="font-style:italic">The Cost of Goods Sold</span> must be a number');
```

or if you want to append multiple errors messages within the same div:

```
$('#divError').append("The Cost of Goods Sold must be a number<br />");
$('#divError').append("Another error message...<br />");
```